# ColorData in 3D plotting

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I was reading [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D5565f53b5cd9e376398b4570%26assetKey%3DAS%253A273784819388434%25401442286795768&ved=2ahUKEwjw-OS0y-TvAhUhyIUKHbOxCqkQFjAPegQIDxAC&usg=AOvVaw1L9GP5sbQsWG-VvBBkx9kn&cshid=1617539535237) and I don't understand what is happening at page 16. What does it mean to have `Abs[Round[10#1]&]` after `ColorData`? What do they code for and what are their arguments?

Comment: The documentation for [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) tells you what the arguments are for the different types of plots. For `Plot3D` the notional arguments are `x, y, z`. This is also shown in the documentation for `Plot3D`. `#1` or just `#` refers to the first argument, i.e., notional `x`.

Comment: Yes, what I don't understand is what numbers `Abs` , which as far as I understand gives the absolute value of a complex number, is referring to here. Also `Round[x]` should give the integer closest to $x$, which here is maybe represented by `#1`, but I don't see what `10` stands for or either `&` at the end.

Comment: The `ColorFunction` assigns a color to each `{x, y, z}`point used in the plot. In this specific case, it is only using the first coordinate to determine the color. It multiplies the first coordinate by 10, rounds the product, and takes the absolute value of the rounded value. This is then the argument to the specified `ColorData` color scheme. Since the `ColorFunctionScaling` is `False` it is using the raw `{x, y, z}` values rather than scaling each coordinate to the interval `{0, 1}`. `Abs` also works on real numbers. `Abs[-10]` is `10`

Comment: Thanks, now it’s perfectly clear. If you want, you can turn this comment into an answer, so that I can accept it

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.